# Format output text file

Tags: file, haskell, io, output

During my current side project in Haskell I have reached my first annoyance with the file writing. 
When I output my text to a file, it is written with no line breaks in-between. I cannot seem to format the output text file in any way.

Is there some obvious solution that I'm missing here?

EDIT: Added the code in question

```
main :: IO ()
main = do 
  args    <- getArgs
  article <- loadArticle $ head args 
  let summary = summarize article
  writeFile (args !! 1) summary 
  mapM_ putStrLn summary
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you would show us a little code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably missing `putStrLn` which add a new line.

Your question is about writing in a file. `writeFile` writes a string, therefore
you have to add manually the `\n` whereever you want a new line.
Otherwise, you can use the file version of `putStrLn` : `hPutStrLn` which take a *handle* as parameter. The handle can be obtainer with `openFile`.

Those functions are in `System.Io`.

Comment: That is for writing text to the console. I don't see how that could be used for files?